# Show an error when sum value is over 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

I'm trying to sum 100 on a variable ammount of input fields. I'm doing this using this Javascript:

```
$('.price').keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;

    $('.price').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    $('#totalPrice').val(sum);
});
```

And it works! but now i need to do two things; if the user inputs a value different than a number, or if the total value is over 100, show a hidden div.

I'm really new Javascript, and i made this code but showing an error are major words for me now.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want something like this:

```js
$('.price').keyup(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.price').each(function() {
    var inputVal = +$(this).val(); //each field's value converted to number using "+"
    if (!isNaN(inputVal)) {
      sum += inputVal;
      $('.not-num-err').hide();
    } else {
      $('.not-num-err').show();
      return false; //stop iteration
    }
  });
  if (sum > 100) {
    $('.over-hundred-err').show();
  } else {
    $('.over-hundred-err').hide();
  }
  $('#totalPrice').val(sum);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="price">
<input type="text" class="price">
<input type="text" class="price">
<div class="not-num-err hidden">You entered wrong number</div>
<div class="over-hundred-err hidden">Total is over 100!</div>
<p>
  <label for="totalPrice">Total Price</label>
  <input type="text" id="totalPrice">
```

check this [link](http://frontendplay.com/2013/05/25/plus-sign-javascript/) for more info on the unary plus (`+`) operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` keyword inside it:

```
$('.price').keyup(function() {
  if (isNaN(this.value) || (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value > 100)) {
    // Do something.
    alert("No!");
    // Do not allow the function to proceed.
    return false;
  }
  var sum = 0;

  $('.price').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });

  $('#totalPrice').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: This is better combined with isNaN somewhere as it wont eliminate non-numeric values as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/ydbjsx1z/

Try this:

```
$('.price').keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
        if(sum <= 100)
        {
              $('.error').html("");
        sum += Number($(this).val());
      }
      else {
        $('.error').html("Sum is greater than 100").css("color","red");
      }
    });
        $('#totalPrice').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: how about when user enters something that is not a number?

Comment: I took input type="number"; so it is not possible to input any text.
https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/ydbjsx1z/

Comment: OP said: > "if the ***user inputs a value different than a number***, or if the total value is over 100, show a hidden div.", so, meaning, his inputs are `type="text"`